# JSON is simplified after being sent to frontend

Tags: java, json, spring, vue.js, rest

There is a REST controller that sends a list of all messages, one of the parameters of which is the object of the user who created this message.

```
@GetMapping
public List<Message> getAllMessages(@RequestParam(required = false) String filter,
                                    @RequestParam(name = "bytag", required = false) Boolean findByTag,
                                    @PageableDefault(sort = {"creationDate"}, direction = Sort.Direction.DESC, size = 5) Pageable pageable) {
  List<Message> tet = messageService.getAllMessages(filter, findByTag, pageable);
  return tet;
}
```

At this stage, everything works correctly and all user data is correct.
[image]
But when displayed on the frontend, only the id remains from all the User data.
[image]
Also at the very beginning of this list it says **This value was evaluated upon first expanding**. What could be the reason for such data clipping and how can it be fixed?

Here's my frontend code.

```
<div v-for="message in messages" :key="message.id" :id="message.id + 1" class="main-container__post">
      <div class="post_profile_name">
        <router-link
          :to="{ name: 'Profile', params: { username: message.user.username }}">
          <h1>{{ message.user.username }}</h1>
        </router-link>
      </div>
```

```
  fetchMessages() {
  let byTag = this.$store.state.byTag
  let toFindText = this.$store.state.toFindText
  console.log(byTag)
  console.log(toFindText)
  // get request for all message in database
  fetch("/api/message?filter=" + toFindText + "&bytag=" + byTag + "&page=" + this.pageNumber)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data.length === 0)
          console.log("That's all messages!") // todo Alert of insufficient messages
        console.log(data)
        this.messages = this.messages.concat(data.filter(item =>
            !JSON.stringify(this.messages).includes(JSON.stringify(item))
        ))
        this.$store.state.messages = this.messages
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('messages getting', error)
      })
  console.log(this.messages)
  this.pageNumber++
},
```

Here I just send a get request and output returned data.

Comment: This sounds like an issue (if an issue at all) with your frontend code or the way you debug. Can you share your frontend code ?

Comment: I added my frontend code.

Comment: Can you try with !JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.messages)).includes(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item))) instead of  !JSON.stringify(this.messages).includes(JSON.stringify(item)) ?

Comment: Nothing has changed

Comment: You're trying to solve it in inefficient way because you use indirect clues. Instead you need to isolate the problem to either front or back end. The question should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve which you won't be able to provide because there can be multiple points of failure that aren't shown. The response can be clearly seen in devtools, it doesn't make sense to use another layer (Vue) to debug it. If the response is correct, re-ask the question for front end only. If it's not, then for back end. From what you posted, I'd expect it to be backend, and so frontend is irrelevant

Comment: Use a tool like curl or httpie to call the _/api/message_ endpoint of you backend and check what you get there. If it is alright, then the problem is in the frontend, if not it's the backend.